# How to kill an app along with all its threads/process

Tags: android

I have LVL licnensing implemented. Sometimes the progress bar keeps showing "Checking for license" and it gets stuck there. I tried my best to find out where this is happening but no luck. The problem that when it happens, the progress bar stays on and the access to the application is blocked (even the backbutton does not work) and you have to hit home. When you click on the app again it brings up the same progress bar. The only time to get it to work is and do a another license check is by force killing the app.

Soooo, my question is. I gave up on knowing why the app is getting stuck (cant post code as it is 1000 lines of code for LVL only). What I need help with is how can I get out of the stuck stat when user press back or home? Is there a way I can kill my app and all the background process associated with it (LVL checking) so when the person clicks on the app again, it starts from scratch

Thank you

Comment: Did u try putting a finish() in onBackPressed() ?

Comment: Wouldnt that finish the activity but leave a th licensing thread hanging in there

Comment: Are you using a Asynctask.?

Comment: Though not recommended but - you can try - android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: I tried overwriting Back button but no luck. Not even getting hit when I press back. It only responds to Home button. Whyyy :(  any ideas?

Comment: Try to catch the back button event in onKeyDown . See if this works?

Comment: Show us the code where you are stuck!

Comment: @Ares, if you read in my question I said I will not post 1000 lines of code as I have no idea where it is stuck

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

This will close your application and kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Add a cancelListner to the the progressDialog as apperently it is not cancellable by default. Adding cancell operation will give the Backbutton its power again and I kill the thread